# Getting correct row and column names when reading with read.csv2

Tags: r, csv, import-from-csv

I have the following CSV file:

```
;A;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;K;L;M;N;P;Q;R;S;T;V;W;X;Y
Position1;0,054213776;0,003005945;0,027905128;0,00375423;0,290228233;0,064954976;0,002462278;0,047134442;0,005404894;0,081739388;0,002012803;0,046380669;0,020762236;0,03654459;0,057469835;0,011760176;0,002482397;0,026511666;0,108202585;0,011974854;0,058416108
Position2;0,004057157;0,041518985;0,019806132;0,051610208;0,003572703;0,036402843;0,074879075;0,010325334;0,044981263;0,09328763;0,03897166;0,064762246;0,029074767;0,004175355;0,013691361;0,109767515;0,046100376;0,002930728;0,248865169;0;0,028268182
Position3;0,051305224;0,064958634;0,025061506;0,001931642;0,022646096;0,053596034;0,060665537;0,002355053;0,002426384;0,264133805;0,030836312;0,032183821;0,018242803;0,048333116;0,11381004;0,066739613;0,052130556;0,005772064;0,047369009;2,92638E-05;0,033100145
```

Basically, my row names are Position1, Position2, Position3 and my column names are A, B, C....,Y. I have loaded them in R using the following command:

```
 data<- read.csv2(f, header=TRUE)
```

where f has been selected before.

However, if I ask for the row names using `data[,1]` I get

```
[1] Position1 Position2 Position3
Levels: Position1 Position2 Position3
```

which seems ok. However, if I now ask for the column names via `data[1,]` I get the following:

```
          X          A           C          D          E         F          G           H          I           K          L           M          N          P          Q          R          S           T          V         W        X.1
1 Position1 0.05421378 0.003005945 0.02790513 0.00375423 0.2902282 0.06495498 0.002462278 0.04713444 0.005404894 0.08173939 0.002012803 0.04638067 0.02076224 0.03654459 0.05746983 0.01176018 0.002482397 0.02651167 0.1082026 0.01197485
           Y
1 0.05841611
```

which I do not understand. For some reason R thinks that the first element [1,1] should have a name and uses `X` for that while in the CSV file the first element is empty, i.e.

```
[1,1]=empty   A   C   D   E..........Y
Position1
Position2
Position3
```

How should I read the CSV file in **R**?

Edit: I removed the semicolon and used the following command: `data<- read.table(f, header=TRUE, sep=";")`
However, if I now want to ask for the rownames via `data[,1]` I get the following:

```
[1] 0,054213776 0,004057157 0,051305224
Levels: 0,004057157 0,051305224 0,054213776
```

while the column names via `data[1,]` are:

```
                    A           C           D          E           F           G           H           I           K           L           M           N           P          Q           R           S           T           V           W
Position1 0,054213776 0,003005945 0,027905128 0,00375423 0,290228233 0,064954976 0,002462278 0,047134442 0,005404894 0,081739388 0,002012803 0,046380669 0,020762236 0,03654459 0,057469835 0,011760176 0,002482397 0,026511666 0,108202585
                    X           Y
Position1 0,011974854 0,058416108
```

This is still not correct. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
dat <- read.csv2("csvex.txt",row.names=1)
```

will do what you want.

```
rownames(dat)
## [1] "Position1" "Position2" "Position3"
dat[,1]
## [1] 0.054213776 0.004057157 0.051305224
dat["Position1",]
##                    A           C          D  ...
## Position1 0.05421378 0.003005945 0.02790513  ...
dat[1,] ## same as dat["Position1",]
```

The row names and column names in an R `matrix` or `data.frame` are not considered part of the table data (that is, they're not the first row and column of the data) -- rather, they are kept as separate attributes, which are retrievable using `colnames(dat)` and `rownames(dat)` (and settable using `rownames(dat) <- ...` and `colnames(dat) <- ...`).  `dimnames()` is useful for retrieving or setting both column and row names at the same time ...

`header=TRUE` (which is the default for `read.csv[2]`) tells R that it should treat the first row of the CSV file as column names (rather than assuming they're data, and that it should make up generic column names).  `row.names=1` tells R that it should treat the first column of the CSV file as row names (ditto).

Comment: Ok with rownames(dat) I indeed get the correct rownames. How do I obtain the column names? Thanks

Comment: shockingly enough, `colnames(dat)` (or `names(dat)`, if the tabular object is a data frame rather than a matrix [which it is in this case]; `colnames(dat)` works in either case).  By the way, `?rownames` brings up a help page that also tells you about `colnames` ...

Answer (score 0):

You have a semi-colon preceding A in the header row.  I wonder if that's wreaking havoc on the read?  Remove it and see.

Comment: So I removed the semi-colon preceding A, and then used the command as suggested in the previous post: data<- read.table(f, header=TRUE, sep=";")

Comment: No, rownames via data[,1] I get the following: [1] 0,054213776 0,004057157 0,051305224 Levels: 0,004057157 0,051305224 0,054213776 while the column names via data[1,] are also not correct. But it is better then before.

Comment: Shouldn't you summary(data) to see what's going on?